# Applying expression functions

Tags: linq, expression, predicate

I need to implement filter function with expression parameter.
So i can't apply filtered query to entity.

Entity :

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Zip")]
public class Zip
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "code")]
    public string Code { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "District")]
public class District
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Zip")]
    public List<Zip> Zip { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "City")]
public class City
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "District")]
    public List<District> District { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "code")]
    public string Code { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "AddressInfo")]
public class AddressInfo
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "City")]
    public List<City> City { get; set; }
}
```

Test case filtered by City name "Berlin". How can apply predicate with function.

```
public IConverter<T> Filter(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
{
    // ???
    return this;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I presume you need to filter a collection with a given predicate.

You can define a Filter extension method that takes a predicate as an argument (or simply rely on the already existing *collection.Where* extension method)

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> Filter<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection, Func<T, bool> predicate)
    {
        return collection.Where(predicate);
    }
}
```

define predicates based on your needs

```
// Filter by city Berlin
Func<City, bool> berlin = city => city.Name == "Berlin";

// Filter by district Spandau
Func<City, bool> spandau = city => city.Districts.Any(d => d.Name == "Spandau");

// Filter by zip 10115
Func<City, bool> zipcode = city => 
{
    var predicate = from district in city.Districts
                    from zip in district.Zips
                    where zip.Code == "10115"
                    select zip;

    return predicate.Any();
};
```

filter the data based on given predicate

```
var query = from address in addresses
            from city in address.Cities.Filter(berlin)
            select city;
```

[image]